# Errow when displaying the details of a patient when I'm using this serial format LNSD_123122_LMV

Tags: javascript, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Hello how can I fix this,

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column
> 'LNSD_123122_LMV' in 'where clause' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\HMO_Home\view_medicalrecord.php:89 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\HMO_Home\view_medicalrecord.php(89):
> mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM m...') #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\HMO_Home\view_medicalrecord.php on line 89

This error show when I'm using this serial format (LNSD_123122_LMV), but when the patients has pure number of format (029029) it showing its details.

Here is my query code

```
<?php 
                        
    $familynumber = $row['family_number'];
    
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM medical_itr WHERE family_number LIKE 
    $familynumber";
    $medical_itr = $con->query($sql1) or die ($con->error);
    $row = $medical_itr->fetch_assoc();

                
?>
```

Comment: Problem Solved Just did this

Comment: $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM medical_itr WHERE family_number LIKE 
                   ' $familynumber"';